# Localhost web site with MySQL and Python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, mysql, localhost

I have `MySQL 8` and `Python 3.8` on my workstation based on `Mac OS X 10.13`. I use `Homebrew` on my Terminal to install to the server.

I want to use a browser with JavaScript/jQuery to send AJAX requests to Python which would query MySQL and return a result to jQuery.

I can presently send the jQuery.ajax request to my localhost server and I am able to use Python from my Terminal to manipulate the MySQL database.

What I don't know is how to execute a Python code as part of the AJAX request from the client. Not looking for someone to give me a solution - I want to learn this myself, but I am confused about where to go next.

Can someone just point me to the right direction? If there is a more direct way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: ajax has to send request to server www which runs Python www framework like Flask, Django and it has to run code and send result as response (HTML page). Eventuall www server can run PHP which can use `exec()` to execute python script (or any other program) on server and send result in response as HTML page. Eventuall you can use www server which can use CGI and run scripts in any language (Python, PERL, Ruby, Bash, C/C++ programs, etc). But it is very old method and prefered is first method with Flask, Django, Bottle, etc.

Comment: [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/) (see `Web Development`)

Comment: Thanks. That's the kind of advice I was seeking. I will look further into Flask and Django. The process continues... :)

Comment: I can recommend you [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/cr3l7z/a_beginners_introduction_to_python_web_frameworks/) thread which compares web frameworks for python.